# fadeIn/fadeOut functions not working

Tags: javascript

I am working on fadein and fadeout functions using pure javascript, here is the code:

```
<script>
function fadeIn(el, ms) {
    var opacity = 1,
    interval = 50,
    gap = interval / ms;

    window.setInterval(function{ 
        opacity -= gap;
        el.style.opacity = opacity;
        if(opacity <= 0) {
            window.clearInterval(fading); 
            el.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }, interval);
}
function fadeOut(el, ms){
    var opacity = 0,
    interval = 50,
    gap = interval / ms;
    el.style.display = 'block';
    el.style.opacity = opacity;
    window.setInterval(function{ 
        opacity += gap;
        el.style.opacity = opacity;
        if(opacity >= 1) {
            window.clearInterval(fading);
        }
    }, interval);   
}
</script>
```

And in the body section, code is:

```
<input type="button" onclick="fadeOut(this, 50);" value="hi" />
```

Immediately when page loads it gives an error "error unexpected token (" :

```
window.setInterval(function{
```

And when I try to click the input button, I get the error:  "cant find variable fadeIn"

Comment: you can't use setInterval within a function, keep it outside and call your function within setInterval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing parenthesis for the function declaration:

```
setTimeout(function() {

});
```

Note the addition of `()` after the `function` keyword. You need do this for both `setTimeout` functions in `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`

Comment: That takes care of the errors, but the button still won't fade out.

Comment: @TekiTech In that case, you have a separate issue. You should ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct Code
you need to add () after the "anonymous function" written in the `window.setInterval(function{`

```
<script>
function fadeIn(el, ms) {
    var opacity = 1,
    interval = 50,
    gap = interval / ms;

    window.setInterval(function(){ 
        opacity -= gap;
        el.style.opacity = opacity;
        if(opacity <= 0) {
            window.clearInterval(fading); 
            el.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }, interval);
}
function fadeOut(el, ms){
    var opacity = 0,
    interval = 50,
    gap = interval / ms;
    el.style.display = 'block';
    el.style.opacity = opacity;
    window.setInterval(function(){ 
        opacity += gap;
        el.style.opacity = opacity;
        if(opacity >= 1) {
            window.clearInterval(fading);
        }
    }, interval);   
}
</script>
```